# Command not working in the middle of a Heroku tutorial

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am following a tutorial in Heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) and hit the problem hereafter, when running the command:

```
% heroku local web
```

On a Mac (M1), though all the first part of the tutorial went fine, in the section *Run the app locally*, this is what I get (not what is supposed to happen):

```
myveryname@Me-MacBook-Air node-js-getting-started % heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
2:20:52 PM web.1 |  > node-js-getting-started@0.3.0 start
2:20:52 PM web.1 |  > node index.js
2:20:52 PM web.1 |  node:events:491
2:20:52 PM web.1 |        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2:20:52 PM web.1 |        ^
2:20:52 PM web.1 |  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1432:16)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at listenInCluster (node:net:1480:12)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Server.listen (node:net:1568:7)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Function.listen (/Users/myveryname/Documents/Heroku/node-js-getting-started/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myveryname/Documents/Heroku/node-js-getting-started/index.js:10:4)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |  Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at emitErrorNT (node:net:1459:8)
2:20:52 PM web.1 |      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2:20:52 PM web.1 |    code: 'EADDRINUSE',
2:20:52 PM web.1 |    errno: -48,
2:20:52 PM web.1 |    syscall: 'listen',
2:20:52 PM web.1 |    address: '::',
2:20:52 PM web.1 |    port: 5000
2:20:52 PM web.1 |  }
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
2:20:52 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
myveryname@Me-MacBook-Air node-js-getting-started %
```

Searching the net seems to suggest that Mac may make use of the 5000 port on its own.
When I look at http://localhost:5000/ in my web browser, it looks like the port 5000 is indeed somewhat busy (though the page shows completely white).
But I have no idea what it is doing. And even if I restart the computer that does not change.

I must not be the only one to have hit this issue. So what is the correct way to handle this situation and be able to continue with the end of the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mac Air Play Control Center listens on port 5000.
You can disable airplay receiver to release the port or you can change the port on your code to something like 5001

you can also run this command `lsof -i :5000` to check which process is using 5000 port

Reference:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I used the "lsof -i :5000" command and saw the result. But as for the solution, I am using Mac OS Ventura (13.0) and the explanation in the link you mention doesn't seem to be valid to disable airplay. I found something helpful for that here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254343678. Beside, for your second solution, how do you change the code to another port? I changed 5000 to 5001 in index.js, but it didn't do the job.

Comment: inside index.js file at line 3 you can change to something like
`const POST = process.env.PORT || 5001` but if it still doesn't work you can run `lsof` to check if that port is really busy and if yes then change to another port

Comment: This is what I did, but it did not work. It seems like this line is ignored.